# Identify a contaminated distribution

Tags: mean, outliers, sample, median

I have a patchy time series of means, medians and sample sizes (n) that occasionally appears to be "contaminated" (either by bad or atypical data). For example:

```
median<-c(605 598 600 752 610 662 600 730 715 650 750 275 675 650 1267 800  675 650)
mean<-  c(682 632 800 886 709 789 730 775 840 810 850 538 685 783 1296 959 2315 707)
n<-     c(159 107 112  39  82  45 122  79  96  73 198 189  79  38  225 174  115 108)
```

Here the penultimate observation has a mean 3.5 times that of the median and is probably "contaminated". Is there a way to use information on just the mean, median and sample size (or neighbouring observations?) to identify a sample that is atypical? On a normality assumption, `mean/median = 1.0`? I do not have access to the original sample observations. Also, here I have data for every quarter, but for other locations there are quarters for which I have no data.

I  found this reference, but it is a bit dated and only covers cases with low N. Dixon, W. J. "Processing data for outliers." Biometrics 9, no. 1 (1953): 74-89. https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3001634.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you may need a measure of spread, to make a test you would need the standard deviation, or the interquartile range or something like that.
In theory, we have that $|E[X]-Median(X)|\le \sigma$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Inequality_relating_means_and_medians))  and in fact this bound is tight you can find distributions for which this is the case so if you have no information on the spread of your numbers, having a 3 times increase between the mean and the median can happen even for non-contaminated data. For example, take a log-normal distribution of parameter $\mu,\sigma$, the median is $\exp(\mu)$ and the mean is $\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$ so depending on $\sigma$ the difference between the mean and the median can be huge and a log-normal distribution is not contaminated by outliers.

Comment: $\sigma$ might not exist for the bad guys...

Comment: It is why I used the term "measure of spread", for example we can also use the inter quartile range, or the median absolute deviation.